# What is the correct way to say "Please select the best one from the available options"?

Tags: grammar

When I read some examination papers, I often found the following instruction.

> 次の文の（　　）に入れるのに最もよいものを、１・２・３・４から一つ選びなさい。

My question is

1. Can I rephrase the instruction above as follows?

   > 次の文の（　　）に入れるのに、１、２、３、４からの最もよいものの一つを選びなさい。
2. Which is the correct format in Japanese for a list of number 1, 2, 3, 4?

   > A: １・２・３・４

   or

   > B: １，２，３，４

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 最もよいものの一つ is inappropriate. It would mean "one of the best", and implies there are more than one choice that can fit the blank. One has to "select the best one", not "select one of the best".
2. Whichever is fine as long as you use punctuation marks consistently throughout your manuscript.